# Проблема с выводом данных sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, telebot, sqlite3

Я пытаюсь вывести данные с помощью fetchall().
Полный код:

```
cursor.execute(f'SELECT exchange_offer_id FROM exchange WHERE exchange_name = "finder"')
exchange = cursor.fetchall()
offers = exchange #тут все данные
print(offers)
```

Результат выглядит следующим образом:

```
[(4,), (3,)]
```

Тип данных самого столбца - NUMERIC.

Вопрос, почему при выводе появляется запятая в самом значении? И как её можно убрать?

Comment: Потому что это кортеж из одного элемента, а в кортеже всегда по синтаксису положено иметь запятую

Comment: Как убрать — ну например `offers = [x[0] for x in exchange]`

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете просто список перебрать и достать первые значения.

```
cursor.execute(f'SELECT exchange_offer_id FROM exchange WHERE exchange_name = "finder"')
exchange = cursor.fetchall()
offers = [x[0] for x in exchange]
print(offers)
```